# ASP.NET Core grpc-Web on IIS returns 404

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-web

.NET Core gRPC-Web client calling ASP.NET Core gRPC-Web server on http://localhost:5000 works fine.

Same client code calling server deployed to an IIS server with a virtual application (e.g., "http://build.mycompany.ca/myapp") results in

Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 404")

My ASP.NET Core 3.1 server is set up correctly.  i.e.,
app.UseGrpcWeb(new GrpcWebOptions { DefaultEnabled = true });

is in between

```
app.UseRouting()
```

and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints
        .MapGrpcService<GrpcClientService>()
        .EnableGrpcWeb();
});
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you find out how to fix this, I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

only the host portion of the URI is used in the Grpc client.  A DelegatingHandler is required to redirect to a subdirectory on the target host.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/880