# Grpc-Web Application hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-web

I have created a sample Grpc application with a basic ado .net query and I want to host the same in the IIS. The application works fine when I consume it from a net client but after hosting, I am getting an error in the client application when I try to consume the grpc endpoint.

1. 'Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 404")'
2. I have created an entity a grpc app with ef core and a WCF service with EF6. when I compare the response times, the WCF service seems to respond quicker than grpc app. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hi @user3406612.Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140815/asp-net-core-grpc-web-on-iis-returns-404)?And did you mind sharing how do you configure your grpc application?

Comment: I'm afraid that in terms of performance comparison, you'd need to provide much more detailed description to make it possible for someone to understand what the issue is and how to help. Ideally, you'd provide two projects with full code that would allow everyone to reproduce your results. From what said, I don know what "responds quicker" means exactly (a few milliseconds slower or a few seconds slower?). I don't see any reason why gRPC server would be noticeably slower than other server (e.g. a WCF service) - definitely not at a level where the user could notice the difference.